# I can use my Java SDK Ubuntu installation when Wine need it?

Tags: wine, java

If I have Java RE in Ubuntu, and I have a program that runs in Wine (Windows) but need java, do I need to install twice Java? It's doesnt exist a way to connect both.

My question is not how to install Java RE in Wine, my cuestion is 100% theory. Why wine can't use my JRE installation instead of installing in windows JRE.

Comment: My question is not how to install Java RE in Wine, my cuestion is 100% theory. Why wine can't use my JRE installation instead of installing in windows JRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't Wine use my JRE installation instead of installing Windows JRE?

Linux executables are generally not compatible with Windows (they do not run in Windows). In particular the Linux versions of JRE are not compatible with Windows programs. Only Windows versions of JRE are compatible with Windows programs, so you need to install the Windows JRE in order for it to be compatible with Windows programs running in Wine.

#### Installation

The link to download the Java file you want is: [Java Downloads for Windows](http://java.com/en/download/windows_manual.jsp?locale=en). Download an Offline Java version. The installation instructions are available at the official [What is the offline method for downloading and installing Java for a Windows computer?](http://java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.xml) webpage.

Answer (score -1):

You could do wine start /unix to launch a native application. In this case you could do something like
"which java" to find the path to java-> let us say that is usr/[somPath]/java

Then do this to launch the native unix Java
"wine start /unix usr/[somPath]/java" to run the native java from wine.